# Convert Lower Case Special Character to UpperCase

Tags: php, string, character, special-characters

I have `ñ` as a special character. It's uppercase equivalent is `Ñ`. I want to convert the lowercase special character to uppercase. I tried the code below:

```
strtouppercase('ñ');
ucfirst('ñ');
ucwords('ñ');
```

But the code above does not convert anything. What shall I do to convert the special character?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php and https://ideone.com/8Qzv4t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strtoupper PHP function for UTF-8 string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969803/strtoupper-php-function-for-utf-8-string)

Answer (score 0):

ASCII value for `'ñ'` is 241. The difference between uppercase and lowercase characters is always 32 so you can use like:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding(chr(241-32), "UTF-8");
```

to print your desired character `Ñ`

*I hope it helps.*

Answer (score 0):

```
mb_strtoupper('ñ', 'UTF-8');
```

for convert to lower case use `mb_strtolower`