# str_replace with htmlspecialchars return empty result

Tags: php

I want to replace all special character (in array), I used htmlspecialchars, but it does not work I found empty result !!

this is my instruction:

```html
str_replace( array('è','é','ê','ë'), 
             array('e','e','e','e'), 
             htmlspecialchars(strtolower("Elément")) );
```

thank's for helping...

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/819507)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you must use `mb_strtolower` instead `strtolower`,

run the snippet below you will find why:

```
<?php

$a = str_replace( array('è','é','ê','ë'), array('e','e','e','e'), htmlspecialchars(strtolower("Elément")) );

echo "\n0.".$a;
echo "\n1.".htmlspecialchars(strtolower("Elément"));
echo "\n2.".strtolower("Elément");
echo "\n3.".mb_strtolower("Elément");
echo "\n4.".htmlspecialchars(mb_strtolower("Elément"));

$a = str_replace( array('è','é','ê','ë'), array('e','e','e','e'), htmlspecialchars(mb_strtolower("Elément")) );


echo "\n5.".$a;
```

see also [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969803/strtoupper-php-function-for-utf-8-string)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slugger, such as https://packagist.org/packages/javiereguiluz/easyslugger