# Opentbs upper not working for special chars like æøå

Tags: opentbs

I have been stuck for a while with this issue.

When I merge a field and want it sent to uppercase I normaly use `[onshow.field;ope=upper]` and it works great for almost all fields but we are sometimes using special chars like æ, ø and å and these are not being sent to upper like the rest.

Are there anyone that know what could be wrong?

Comment: Without knowing OpenTBS in particular, they are probably using a regex (or`strtoupper`) that only catches a-z. A fix could be finding the code that performs the transformation and changing it. A simple change could be adding æ, ø, å to the regex. A better change could be using [`mb_strtoupper`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969803/strtoupper-php-function-for-utf-8-string) so it works for *all* unicode. If you don't figure it out by Monday, I'll return to a computer then and I can give a more specific answer.

Comment: I have implemented a "hack" were I use strtoupper for all vars, and this solves the immediate problem, but it is not a good way to solve it.  I will try to see if I can find the source in the openTBS libary and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through [the source code of OpenTBS](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/demo/tbs_class.php) and searching for "[`upper`](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/demo/tbs_class.php#L1305)", you get to the cryptic constant "[`15`](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/demo/tbs_class.php#L1418)", which signifies conversion to uppercase. It actually does support Unicode conversion:

```
($Loc->OpeUtf8) ? mb_convert_case($CurrVal, MB_CASE_UPPER, 'UTF-8') : strtoupper($CurrVal)
```

And to [enable Unicode](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/demo/tbs_class.php#L1304), it seems that you also need `ope=utf8`. It seems that you can have multiple filters by [separating them with a comma](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/demo/tbs_class.php#L1290), so in your template, you can write:

```
[onshow.field;ope=utf8,upper]
```

Or you could change the source code to always support Unicode by default on [line 1293](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs/blob/master/demo/tbs_class.php#L1293):

```
$Loc->OpeUtf8 = true;
```